# iPad ViewController segues not working within UIActionSheet

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, ipad, uiviewcontroller

I have an app originally developed for iPhone, with a MapViewController as the main screen, and a Help screen and Tutorial screen both called from within a UI ActionSheet.  Works fine for the iPhone.

When run on an iPad, I can't get to the Help screen and get the following runtime error:

```
Warning: Attempt to present <HelpViewController: 0x177076c0>  on <MapViewController: 0x177d7060> which is already presenting <UIAlertController: 0x17732620>
```

If I add the following line of code

```
[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
```

then I do get to the Help screen, but with the following error:

```
Warning: Attempt to dismiss from view controller <MapViewController: 0x17d75660> while a presentation or dismiss is in progress!
```

When I exit the Help screen, the MapView does not come up, however selection a new baseMap brings it back to life.

So, the code runs fine on an iPhone.  On the iPad I get an error that says

1) Don't open a new view with the UIAlertController active, or
2) Don't dismiss the view, because a dismiss is already in progress...

Sure seems like a timing problem to me, I've tried both a "sleep" statement and some code to provide a short delay, neither have helped.

Anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

you have to set action sheet for iPad like below..

```
        UIActionSheet *popup = [[UIActionSheet alloc] initWithTitle:@"Some Title" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel" destructiveButtonTitle:nil otherButtonTitles:nil,nil];
        if(!IS_IPad){
            [popup showInView:[UIApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow];
        }else{
            [popup showFromRect:CGRectMake((CGRectGetWidth(self.view.frame)-200)/2, self.imgLogo.frame.origin.y,200, 200) inView:self.view animated:YES];
        }
```

Surly your action sheet working in both.

Comment: The action sheet works fine, and allows selection of actions equally well on iPhone and iPad, its in the segue that issue arises.  My bad, I forgot to mention that the transition is being done with a performSegueWithIdentifier, as in '[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"ShowHelpSegue" sender:self];'

Answer (score 0):

This warning comes when you are trying to present/dismiss a view with animation while another animation is still in progress. This might be because while making a selection from UIActionsheet it animates and fades away and at the same time another viewcontroller is appearing with animation. It might help if you dismiss the view controller after delay of 0.2 seconds